# Lazy Loading in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, lazy-loading

I have a winform app where I have to get the data from **web service** and show it in UI. As the data is more I want to load the data batch wise(i.e when gets the data initially, it should bring only 10 records from DB and next time next 10 records from DB and so on...). The requirement is every-time I call the Web Service it should give only 10 records but not all, so that data loading time will be less as there are thousands of data.

How to do this.

Can I implement lazy loading in winform ???

Comment: @Cody Gray, Did you mean I have to implement  
BackgroundWorker ??? If yes, any approach for that ?

Comment: Isn't this more simply skip/take from your data set? Yes, given this is a Winform, background worker may be advised to avoid ui blocking if the service is expected to take any amount of time. But the nature of this question seems more to do with simple paging of data sets. .Skip(n).Take(10) where n is 0, 1, 2, etc...

Comment: @Brenston, what I require is every time I make a call, it will only got 10 records but not all, so that data loading time will not be more because there are thousands of data.

Comment: What data access technology do you use? Is the web service your's?

Comment: @agent5566, Web service is a Java Web Service which I am using in my application

Comment: If you haven't access to web service code, then you can do nothing.

Comment: Ok, first of all you should implement some kind of pagination on server side and make API in the web service for this. Then you can use BackgroundWorker (or anything else) in client side WinForms application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to to this is to add paging support to your service and client. Then make the call async and get 10 records per page. If you post you code I can help you with the update.